# Finding the differences between two rows of data, key by key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, comparison, difference

I have two rows of data - always just two rows, but there could be a maximum of around forty columns. The column names are different on a case by case basis, but here is a representative example:

```
id | height | width | colour | in_stock | featured | on_sale
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  30    |  20   |  black | yes      | no       |  yes
2  |  30    |  25   |  red   | yes      | yes      |  no
```

*I want to get all of the differences between those two rows into an array so that I can log what was changed from row 1 to row 2.*

**I thought it array_diff() would do the job!**

So I cheerfully chucked array_diff() at it thus:

```
//Simplified queries for the example

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1";
$rs1     = $conn->Execute($sql1);
$rs1     = $rs1->fields;

$sql2  = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 2";
$rs2      = $conn->Execute($sql2);
$rs2      = $rs2->fields;

//Build first array
foreach($rs1 as $key => $value){
  $data1[$key] = $value;
}

//Build second array
foreach($rs2 as $key => $value){
  $data2[$key] = $value;
}

//Find the differences
$theDifferences = array_diff($data1, $data2);

//Loop through the differences logging the changes
foreach($theDifferences as $field => $value){
 echo "Change found for ".$field."!";
}
```

**Why that doesn't work.**

This "looked like" it was working. Since many columns contain long strings, colour names, dates etc, so when one changed it was duly pushed into the differences array. The problem was (of course) that the multiple "yes" or "no" columns did not behave as I had expected. Thus the result of the code above, for the table example is:

```
colour, width
```

It is not "seeing" the featured or on_sale columns as changed because the data1 array AND the data2 array both contain no's and yes's.

I suppose I need to compare on a key by key basis? Something like the opposite of array_diff_key()? But here I am stuck.

I also considered if this could be done solely with the SQL query, which would I suppose be more efficient, but that is way beyond my SQL ability.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know this is just an example, but may want to patch up `$rs1     = $rs2->fields;` to `$rs1     = $rs1->fields;` on line 5 so that confusion is avoided.

Comment: did you try array_diff_assoc function? it does additional index checks as mentioned in doc [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: Surely the constant is the number of columns?

Comment: @Nate Reynolds - Will do thanks

Comment: @SajeshBahing - I'll check that out, thanks for the link

Comment: @Strawberry - Sorry, not following you, can you elaborate?

Comment: Well, you assert that the number of rows is constant, but the number of columns might change. I'm merely commenting that it should surely be the other way around!!

Comment: @Strawberry - Ah I see. Yes you might think that, but in this odd case the entire table is temporary and only ever used to (temporarily) hold two rows of data on which I run the compare. Then the next time a product is updated the table is dumped and recreated. I am not at all sure this is the best approach, but it's what is happening.

Comment: I am not at all sure this is the best approach either

Comment: @Strawberry I'd be very grateful if you could suggest something better. By the way the concept here is to store the original and updated values for a product so I can log what field was change to an activity log. The CMS I am working with erases a product and reinserts the data every time an update is made, so this way I can intercept that process and insert the original, and then the new, data to this temp table so I can compare the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very nearly there. Maybe something like this after your queries:

```
$theDifferences = array();
foreach($rs1 as $key => $value){
   if ($rs2[$key] != $value){
      $theDifferences[$key] = $value;
   }
}
```

As for SQL, you can use an EXCEPT to get a list of rows which are different between two queries, but you'd still have to loop through the keys and look for nulls - which doesn't save you a whole lot.

Comment: That's cracked it. Thanks very much and also for the SQL advise :)